# Sprite radial interpolation to each degree from 45 degree sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, interpolation, sprite-sheet

Question on how this could be done, if possible.

I have sprites in each of the following directions (up, down, left, right, upright, upleft, downright, and downleft). I am making a similar game to the old school zelda, running around a tile map (using tiled editor).  This is working well, until now, I want to be able to shoot arrows/spells at any location on the map.  I can do so, but the graphics look horrible because my guy will only turn each 45 degrees.

I have corrected this so I can only shoot in the direction my guy is facing, but now I can't hit them if they are not at a 45 degree angle from me.  To fix this, I need to have a sprite at every 1 degree, or somehow combine the images say at 0 degrees (up) and 45 degrees (upright) to be able to get say 10 degrees via interpolation.  Is this possible?  Any ideas on how to do this?

I am looking into working with key animations since I wouldn't have to have so many sprites and use much less video memory (and smoother animations), but I still run into this same problem. Would like to know if this is conceptually possible and if so, a little psuedo code or snipit would be much appreciated.

One other question, if this is possible, do I need to be rendering this via openGL in 3D? Didn't really know if 3d would help in a 2d (orthogonal tile) game, but it might help spells falling look like they are falling downward more than moving across tiles from above to below?

Comment: First, put some paragraph breaks in your question. Second, we would need to be able to see what the sprite looks like to answer this question.

Comment: Can you elaborate please. I am using dummy sprites as of now to get the game working. Trying to figure out what the best way of doing this is.